# How to read JSON data in classic ASP?

Tags: json, asp-classic

This is my JSON data, how can I read it in Classic ASP code? I have tried using `aspJSON.asp` for this to read JSON.

```js
{"data":
[{"message":"is there any surprise for me?",
  "created_time":"2015-10-08T05:49:09+0000",
  "id":"412741762152133_1039612999465003"},
{"message":"is there any surprise for me?",
  "created_time":"2015-10-08T05:49:09+0000",
  "id":"412741762152133_1039612999465003"},
{"message":"is there any surprise for me?",
  "created_time":"2015-10-08T05:49:09+0000",
  "id":"412741762152133_1039612999465003"}]}
```

Comment: The fact you feel some entitlement to receiving an answer tends to make me not want to answer. We are all busy and sacrifice our time to provide help at SO, demanding a fast reply is just disrespectful. Understand you maybe new so take some time to read [ask].

Comment: You say you tried `aspJSON.asp` *(assuming you are referring to [Classic ASP JSON Class](http://www.aspjson.com/))* can you at least show the code you have attempted?, this is just a JSON structure it doesn't show any of your working. Have you tried using the `loadJSON()` method?

Comment: How you get this data? If from client side, you better parse it client side and send to the server ordinary request items.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It depends they could be using a XMLHttp request server-side and returning JSON they then need to parse before updating a database for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have enabled it on your IIS already:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Display properties for the IIS Server
3. Click MIME Types and then add the JSON extension:

   1. File name extension: .json
   2. MIME type: application/json
4. Go back to the properties for IIS Server
5. Click on Handler Mappings

   1. Add a script map
   2. Request path: *.json
   3. Executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
   4. Name: JSON